# Unity sprite movement changing target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this these sprites in my game;

- player
- circle(1)
- circle(2)
- circle(3)
- circle(4)
- circle(5)
- circle(6)

The circles are spaced out. I have managed to make the player move from circle(1) to circle(2) when the spacebar is pressed using the code below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector3 player;
    public GameObject position1;
    public float speed = 30;

    void Update()

    {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        player = position1.transform.position;
        player.z = transform.position.z;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I need the player to 'zap' to the circles one by one **each time the spacebar is pressed**, so from circle(1) to circle (2) to circle(3) to circle(4) and so on...

I would also need a way of going beyond circle(6) and to carry on, in theory, to infinity.

I am coding in C# and using Unity 5.5

Thank you in advance

Comment: What in the world is 'zap'? What's the question about? Maybe  you have an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Also where is the *"changing gameobjects sprites"* part your title is referring to? Your question mentions no such thing

Comment: Zap, sort of like move but much faster @Programmer

Comment: The title was in a rush, I've edited it now @UnholySheep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have the player move towards a target, and to have the target change every time the space bar is pressed, you'll need to do a few simple things.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // You'll need a list of available targets
    public List<Transform> Targets;

    // The speed to move at
    public float Speed = 30;

    // A variable to keep track of the current target
    private int _currentTargetIndex = 0;

    public void Update()
    {
        // Get the current target
        var target = Targets[_currentTargetIndex];

        // Move towards it every frame
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, Speed);

        // If the space bar was pressed this frame
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            // Select the next target
            _currentTargetIndex++;

            // If we've run out of targets, wrap around to the beginning 
            if(_currentTargetIndex >= Targets.Count) 
            {
                _currentTargetIndex = 0;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It comes up with an error of ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index

Comment: Make sure that you've added the targets to the list in the inspector. Drag them onto the `Targets` field one by one.

Comment: Otherwise yes, if this code is fixed it would be exactly what I was looking for. @Jephron

Answer (score 0):

this is a code will work fine . First , you need to have a Rigidbody in your player .  ,than add this code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject position1;
    public GameObject position2;
    public GameObject position3;
    public GameObject position4;
    public GameObject position5;
    public GameObject position6;
    public int PressedTime;
    public float speed = 30;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        PressedTime += 1;
        if (PressedTime == 1)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position1.transform.position, speed);
        }
        if (PressedTime == 2)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position2.transform.position, speed);
        }
        if (PressedTime == 3)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position3.transform.position, speed);
        }
        if (PressedTime == 4)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position4.transform.position, speed);
        }
        if (PressedTime == 5)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position5.transform.position, speed);
        }
        if (PressedTime == 6)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(position6.transform.position * speed);
        }

    }       
}
}
```

and set variable position1 to 6 in inspector

Comment: `PressedTime` should be initialized to a value (e.g.: 0)

Comment: Even though this works,  I needed a code for the target to automatically be changed/increased instead of manually typing in the targets.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
{
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, position1.transform.position, speed);
}
```

For other circle , you can set variable position2 3 4 5 and so on .
and make 'int PressedTime' , when PressedTime is 6 , turn off the code above and addforce to your gameobject toward the 6th circle .

if my code work , don't forget to accept my answer ! :)

Comment: 1. Code without explanations is not considered a good answer for SO. 2. How can you "answer" a question when it is still unclear what OP really wants?

Comment: I have a player and multiple circles. I need a way for the player to move from one circle to the next infinitely without having to manually drag the circle sprite from the inspector. @UnholySheep